# My Program stops printing to console, but continues to run in background. No Exception is thrown

Tags: java

My program Runs and prints the first few `system.out` statements, then stops printing them. There is no exception thrown, and the program continues to run until manually terminated.

I've tried `System.out.flush();` but am not even sure where to put that

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main { 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws 
FileNotFoundException {

        String inputFileStr = args[0];//"input.txt"; 
        String outputFileStr = args[1];//"output.txt";
        String deleteFileStr = args[2];//"CS401Project5Delete_Varner_Sav58.txt";// 
        String replaceFileStr = args[3]; //"CS401Project5Replace_VARNER_SAV58.txt";

        // create files w/ corresponding file names
        try{
        File inputFile = new File(inputFileStr);
        File outputFile = new File(outputFileStr);
        File deleteFile = new File(deleteFileStr);
        File replaceFile = new File(replaceFileStr);

        // create arrayLists
        ArrayList<StringBuilder> deleteArray;
        ArrayList<StringBuilder> replaceArray;
        ArrayList<StringBuilder> inputArray;

        ArrayList<String> inputStringArray = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> tokensArray = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> frequenciesArray = new ArrayList<>();

        // turn Files into arrayLists of StringBuilders
        deleteArray = fileToArray(deleteFile);
        replaceArray = fileToArray(replaceFile);
        inputArray = fileToArray(inputFile);

        System.out.println("# words in original file: " + wordCount(inputArray));

        // create a deleteList object
        DeleteList delete = new DeleteList();
        delete.compareArray(inputArray, deleteArray);
        System.out.println("Word Count After Deleteing noise: " + delete.wordCount(inputArray));
        System.out.flush();
        // create a replacelist object
        ReplaceList replace = new ReplaceList();
        replace.compareArray(inputArray, replaceArray);
        System.out.println("Word count after replacing words: " + replace.wordCount(inputArray));

        System.out.println("New input printed to 'output.txt'");
            }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("File not found");
    }
    }

    // turns a file into an arraylist of string builders
    public static ArrayList<StringBuilder> fileToArray(File fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<StringBuilder> sbArray = new ArrayList<>();

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
 {
                if (!line.isEmpty()) {

Stream.of(line.split("\\s+")).forEachOrdered(word -> array.add(word));
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.printf("Caught Exception: %s%n", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(array.get(i));
            sbArray.add(sb);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < sbArray.size(); i ++) {
            if 
(sbArray.get(i).toString().endsWith(",") || 
sbArray.get(i).toString().endsWith(".") || 
sbArray.get(i).toString().endsWith(" ") 
||sbArray.get(i).toString().endsWith(":")) {

sbArray.get(i).deleteCharAt(array.get(i).length() - 1);
            }
        }
        return sbArray;
    }

    public static int wordCount(ArrayList<StringBuilder> array) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
}






import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DeleteList extends ArrayList<Object> implements MyInterface {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

//constructor

@Override
public ArrayList<StringBuilder> 
compareArray(ArrayList<StringBuilder> inputArray, ArrayList<StringBuilder> deleteArray) {
    for (int i = 0; i < deleteArray.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < inputArray.size(); j++) {
            if (deleteArray.get(i).toString().equals(inputArray.get(j).toString())){
                inputArray.remove(j);
            }
        }
    }
    return inputArray;
}

@Override
public int wordCount(ArrayList<StringBuilder> inputArray) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.size(); i++) {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
}

 import java.util.ArrayList;




 public class ReplaceList extends ArrayList<Object> implements MyInterface {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
public ArrayList<StringBuilder> 
compareArray(ArrayList<StringBuilder> inputArray, ArrayList<StringBuilder> replaceArray) {
    String wordToReplace, wordReplacingWith = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < replaceArray.size(); i++) {
        wordToReplace = replaceArray.get(i).toString();
        wordReplacingWith = replaceArray.get(i +1).toString();
        for (int j = 0; j < inputArray.size(); j++) {
            if (inputArray.get(j).toString().equalsIgnoreCase((wordToReplace))) {
                StringBuilder strB = new StringBuilder();
                strB.append(wordReplacingWith);
                inputArray.set(j, strB);
            }
        }
    }
    return inputArray;
}

@Override
public int wordCount(ArrayList<StringBuilder> inputArray) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.size(); i++) {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
}
```

It should be printing to the console:

- words in the original file :
- words after deleting noise:
- words after replacing words:
- New Input printed to "output.txt" <--- (i haven't coded this part yet)

  **Note:**
  I have to use string builders, implement an interface, and have the 
  delteList and replaceList extend ArrayList & handle all exceptions in 
  main

Comment: This is a lot of code to expect people to go through. The simple explanation though is you have a loop somewhere that execution is getting stuck in.

Comment: What is the output you are getting? And what are those seemingly randomly placed `System.exit()`  supposed to do?

Comment: The output I'm getting is 
Num words in original file: 271
 System.out.println("Word count after replacing 
words: " + replace.wordCount(inputArray));

as for the system.close, those were my attempt at fixing the problem and forgot to delte them

Answer (score 0):

You're problem is this:

ReplaceList#compareArray

```
while (i < replaceArray.size()) {
    wordReplacingWith = replaceArray.get(i + 1).toString();
}
```

You probably want to increment `i` at some point or more likely you need a different counter here.
And those `System.exit()` commands that prevent compilation ;)

---

The only thing I am seeing in the updated version is a potential `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` for

```java
   for (int i = 0; i < replaceArray.size(); i++) {
      ...
      wordReplacingWith = replaceArray.get(i +1).toString();
      ...
   }
```

---

Unrelated to any endless loop problem you might still have:

`DeleteList#compareArray` is likely to skip elements after a remove operation,
as the new element on position j (the former j+1) element is not covered by your loop.

Comment: I've updated it to this: 

for (int i = 0; i < replaceArray.size(); i++) {
   wordToReplace = replaceArray.get(i).toString();
   wordReplacingWith = replaceArray.get(i +1).toString();
   for (int j = 0; j < inputArray.size(); j++) {
    if (inputArray.get(j).toString().equalsIgnoreCase((wordToReplace))) {
     StringBuilder strB = new StringBuilder();
     strB.append(wordReplacingWith);
     inputArray.
     inputArray.set(j, strB);
    }
    System.out.println();
   }
  }

And deleted those system.exit()'s , and it is still not printing past "# after delteing word"

Comment: Sorry, please update your question instead and format your code so that it is readable.

Comment: There is a leftover `inputArray.` that does not belong there? And at this point you should probably just use a debugger to figure out where it is stuck.

Comment: That wasn't supposed to be there. & Thank you, I have no idea how to use a debugger, but i'm sure I can look it up

Comment: Updated the answer. But won't help you if you're program hasn't come crashing down.